# Dependencies will not transfer from VS Code to Azure when deploying function app

Tags: python-3.x, azure, function, dependencies, requirements.txt

I made an Azure function app that works perfectly fine locally but when I deploy to Azure I get the message:

"Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'."

In the Output of the deployment there is a message:

"Could not find setup.py or requirements.txt; Not running pip install."

I have filled out my requirements.txt file in the format:

requests==2.28.0
pyodbc==4.0.32
etc...

which from what I've gathered is the correct format.

yet these dependencies are not added when I deploy the function. I am using Python 3.9.7. When I deploy the function the only package that is installed is the azure.functions package.

Why can Azure not find my file?

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to deploy the function from VS Code to Azure using the latest versions as well as previous versions of python successfully.

[image]

[image]

**Publish to Azure Function App:**

Output console:

[image]

Try to run the below cmdlet for this error -

Could not find setup.py or requirements.txt; Not running pip install.

```html
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Also refer this document to troubleshoot this type of errors.

If you are getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'" error then it indicates that either the requests module is not installed or, if it is, that Python cannot locate it. If it isn't already installed, you can do it quickly by using the command

```html
python3 -m pip install requests
```